# Node JS, Unable to fetch mongo connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to node.js, I am trying to fetch mongoDB connection below but it does not return anything or print anything to console. What am i doing wrong?

**dataSource-Mongo.js**:

```
function getMongoDB(hostURL,db){

    var mongoDB = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    return mongoDB.connect(hostURL,function(err,db){

        if(err){
            console.log('Unable to connect to mongo server. Error : ', err);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Connection established to Mongo Database @ ', hostURL);
        }
    }); 
    }

        module.exports.getMongoDB = getMongoDB;
```

**test-Connection.js**

```
var testDB = require('./dataSource-Mongo');

testDB.getMongoDB("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
```

Here is the Structure :

[image]

Comment: Did your code work correctly when your wrapper function is not exported? Have you tried it?

Comment: Then, can you try to remove second parameter in `getMongoDB` function `db` parameter.

Comment: When I run testConnection.js, it returns cannot find module dataSource-Mongo

Comment: Ok it gives you error in console, so in require please give the correct path. what is your exact path structure now ?

Comment: I have my dataSource-Mongo.js file under public folder. I've tried with the path "./public/dataSource-Mongo", it's still giving the same error. what path should I provide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86931/discussion-between-lker-korkut-and-siddarth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is about the path while pointing in require.

You should use `require("../public/dataSource-Mongo");`

Extra :

Also you can create a global variable like `global.__basepath = __dirname + "/";` this so you will reach imported js files `var testdb = require( __basepath + "public/dataSource-MongoDB");` like this.